# Facebook chat -- offline friends shown above online friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

With the new FB sidebar chat application, I am getting a subset of my friends always visible on the sidebar, regardless of their online status

Others appear in the More friends section when they are online

Any idea why this is happening?

Shouldnt the online friends be displayed at the top of the list, followed by the offline friends. Or display only the online frineds?

(old FB chat had this feature IIRC)

[image]
^^This is the main part of the sidebar. Note that very few friends are online
To view the others I have to scroll to the More Online Friends section
[image: All the online friends are visible in this list]

All the online friends are visible in this list

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have been fixed by Facebook today (for me). Wait for a couple of days for the changes to roll out for everybody.

If you cant wait then use the trick mentioned here.. http://thenextweb.com/facebook/2011/07/26/how-to-fix-facebook-chat-so-you-can-see-whos-really-online-again/

Comment: Just an update, FB doesnt seem to have fixed it for me atleast.

Comment: No it has been rolled back for me also. Dunno why..